How to configure timeout in code (not in application.yml)?
How do you set the timeout in code, not in an application.yml file?
E.g. we can do this to set the log level:
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}

Is there something similar for timeout?

Please don't tag your title question. See [ask].

Did you try with these options, passing it from command line
-Dfeign.client.config.default.connectTimeout=1000
-Dfeign.client.config.default.readTimeout=1000


Found the answer:
@Value("${feign.connectTimeout:10000}")
private int connectTimeout;

@Value("${feign.readTimeOut:300000}")
private int readTimeout;

@Bean
public Request.Options options() {
    return new Request.Options(connectTimeout, readTimeout);
}

